# Install GNOME without working internet connection

Tags: 11.10, gnome, wireless, xfce

I switched to XFCE from GNOME, and then I deleted GNOME. Now that I have restarted my computer, XFCE will not start. I have tried re-installing GNOME using apt-get, but I am unable to connect to my wireless connection from the command line.

I have another computer (which is running Windows), so I would like to know if there is some way I can download GNOME on that computer, put it on a flash drive, and then install it from my flash drive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because we don't know for sure what else may have been removed by purging GNOME, and because of the so many other dependencies GNOME has the least time consuming and a secure way to get a functional and running system back would be a clean reinstall of Ubuntu (e.g. from a flash pen).

Make sure not to delete your `/home` directories by choosing **upgrade 11.10 to 11.10**. This will preserve all settings you may have made.